# How to import local project with existing files to Source tree

Tags: git, tree

I'm using Source tree. But I have existing project folder with files in it. I want to import project folder to Source Tree. I tried to remove files from project and then add folder to Source Tree with:

> Clone/New

After that I added my project files. But I can't commit and push my changes and it's not showing latest changes when I change file from project.
I've read questions and I couldn't find in Source Tree menu :

```
Repositories > import repository
```

How to import my project?

Comment: Are you sure it is a GIT folder? Does it has a .git subfolder in its root folder?

Comment: No, it isn't. I have to make it git repository but there are files in it. I'll try answer of @oshnaps!

Comment: You can't load a non-git folder into SourceTree as it was a git project!

Comment: Yes, but how to make it git repository if I have files in my project?

Comment: hi, any solution for that so far? i wanted to store 50 to 60 older projects on sourcetree to share with colleges.  Meh....can't do. need to do 5 steps on the console for every project. Feeling like a monkey. Live could be easy. R-Click -> Make it a loc+remot Repo...done

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like you're missing the .git folder.
You should:

1. Create a new empty repository on your git client.
2. Clone it by source tree.
3. Copy the .git folder to your existing project folder.

At this point source tree should alarm you that the repository local location was changed, just follow it's interface in order to change the location, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. I've missed step 2.

Comment: I would love to love Sourcetree but this drives me crazy EVERY time.

By now, I would've expected that this would be supported: Here's my project, I create a new online repo and ST adds the files to the existing project. Simple. But no.

And then you get this kind of thing: "Invalid slug. Slugs must be lowercase, alphanumerical, and may also contain underscores, dashes, or dots." Seriously?

Comment: This drives me mental; you'd think by now there would be a SourceTree "Import Project/Solution" or "Add Existing Project/Solution" native tool/utility. Like many people, I often start a project then think "Oh, I should add this to SourceTree now that it's down the track a bit". And then I have to jump through a number of hoops to get it done when it could - should - be a 1 min job.

Comment: hi, any solution for that so far? i wanted to store 50 to 60 older projects on sourcetree to share with colleges. Meh....can't do. need to do 5 steps on the console for every project. Feeling like a monkey. Live could be easy. R-Click -> Make it a loc+remot Repo...done . I have tried sourcetree, gitlab, gitkraken and fork. They all have the same issue. they cannot create a local plus remote repo in 1 step. I wish i would still have source sfae

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not a git folder (it doesn't have a .git sub-folder in its root folder), you just need to do the following (in command line):

```
cd root-folder
git init
```

Comment: Yes, I did it through console. After that I couldn't commit my changes in branch that I use and pushed them in new branch. There was error that I can't push them.

Comment: It means that you maybe trying to load a folder to SourceTree from a within a git repository but not by selecting the root folder of the git repository.
Delete the created .git folder and select the correct root folder

Comment: I can clone project from git, but how to add my local files?

Comment: OK, I've read again your initial question...
If I understand correctly, you have an existing git repository that you've cloned locally and now you have an additional project-code that were not in the cloned repository that you want to add to it.
It depends in what format this project it is (java? js?), but basically you should:

1. copy the project folder into the root of your cloned repository
2. cd (in console) to the root folder
3. run: **git add --all** or **git add project-folder**
and then you'll be able to see it in SourceTree and commit it

Comment: No, I don't have local repository at all. I have local project files that aren't repository and I have git repository that I haven't cloned. My project is written in php. How to do it if I don't have git repositoy local?

Comment: You must clone the repository locally if you want to add a project to it (as I've described above).
The other option is that the new project will be a stand-alone repository with its own branches, not related to the remote repository (for that **git init** will do the job)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96931/discussion-between-yorammi-and-mistery-girl).

Comment: But if I clone repository, my local files would be overwritten? Maybe I have to copy project files from prohect folder. Then I clone repository. And finally to put my project files in it. Is it right? :)